# Garbage Collection Never Runs for Springboot Maven Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have a Springboot Maven project that uses a @JmsListener to read messages from a queue.

If no events are coming in, the heap memory slowly increases. When messages are coming the heap memory is ramping up fast. But the heap memory never comes down (check image below).

If I add System.gc() atthe end of the receiver method The garbage collector is doing its job as expected. But this is definately not good practice.

How can I ensure that gc will runn at appropriate times. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Heap Memory Usage**

[image: Heap Memory Usage]

**Receiver method**

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${someDestination}", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(Message message){
        if (message instanceof BytesMessage) {
            try {
                List<Trackable> myList;

                BytesMessage byteMessage = (BytesMessage) message;
                byte[] byteData = new byte[(int) byteMessage.getBodyLength()];
                byteMessage.readBytes(byteData);

                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(new String(byteData))));

                TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
                Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc.getElementsByTagName(SOME_TAG_NAME).item(0)), new StreamResult(writer));
                String outputXmlString = writer.getBuffer().toString();

                XMLInputFactory xmlFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
                XMLStreamReader xmlReader = xmlFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(outputXmlString));

                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);

                MyEvent myEvent = ((JAXBElement<MyEvent>) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xmlReader)).getValue();
                myList = myService.saveEvent(myEvent);

                LOGGER.info(String.format("Received message with EventID: %s and successfully inserted into database", myEvent.getID()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " in Receiver: ", e);
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Received unsupported message format from MQ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: “ramping up fast” by a whopping 40MB… You have a heap size of ~4GB and are wondering why the JVM doesn’t waste CPU cycles to reclaim less than 175MB ( 0.175GB)?

Comment: Oke, so GC does not run untill the memory reaches a certain limit. I was under the assumption it would also run when the application was idle. Thanks

Comment: It depends on the configured GC algorithm(s). Concurrent garbage collectors won’t wait until the memory is full, still they usually have thresholds much larger than 5% of the configured heap size. If 175MB are really a concern, you have to do either, configure the thresholds manually or reduce the maximum heap size. Otherwise, you’ve proven that explicit GC can reclaim the memory, so there are no leaks and you can be fine with just letting the JVM fill the heap memory and run the GC when needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why? Because the `JVM` decided (based on its heuristics) that it's not yet the time to run. When is the time to run though, depends on heap size and GC algorithm. Generally, running a GC cycle is, by no means, a free operation - it requires GC cycles + stopping your application for some period of time (called `stop-the-world` events), at least. As such, GC algorithms run when they need to.

When you are using a concurrent collector (`ZGC` or `Shenandoah` for example), it does not matter *too* much if they run or not; this is because they are *concurrent*: they run while your application is running. They do have `stop-the-world` pauses - but these are very small (unlike `G1GC` for example in certain cases). Because of this concurrency they *can* be forced to run "every X seconds"; `Shenandoah` has `-XX:ShenandoahGuaranteedGCInterval=10000` (we use this in production).

But I assume you are using `G1GC` (i.e. this is what you get if you do not enable a GC at all). This particular GC is *mostly* concurrent and is *generational*. It splits the heap in *young* and *old* regions and collects them independently. Young regions are collected under a `STW` pause, while a `Full GC` (collects old regions) is *mostly* concurrent: it can stretch a `STW` pause to minutes, literally, but it's not the general case.

So, when you use `G1GC`, a young GC cycle will be triggered when *all* young Eden regions (young regions are split in Eden and Survivor further) are full. A Full GC cycle will be triggered when one of the 3 happens :

```
 1) IHOP is reached 
 2) G1ReservePercent is reached 
 3) a humongous allocation happens (an allocation that spans across multiple regions - think huge Objects).
```

But this is rather a simplistic and somehow incomplete picture of when a `GC cycle` happens for `G1GC`, mainly because any of those 3 will actually trigger a `mark` phase (a certain portion of the entire Full GC), that will decide what to do next based on the data it gathers from regions. It usually triggers a *young GC* immediately and *then* a `mixed Collection`, but may be a different path is selected (again, based on the data that a GC has).

So overall, you have too little pressure on the heap for a `GC cycle` to be initiated and most of the time - this is exactly what you want.